# Displaying animated GIFs in Tkinter using PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I'm trying to make a program to display an animated GIF using Tkinter. Here is the code that I originally used:

```
from __future__ import division # Just because division doesn't work right in 2.7.4
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import threading
from time import sleep

def anim_gif(name):
    ## Returns { 'frames', 'delay', 'loc', 'len' }
    im = Image.open(name)
    gif = { 'frames': [],
            'delay': 100,
            'loc' : 0,
            'len' : 0 }
    pics = []
    try:
        while True:
            pics.append(im.copy())
            im.seek(len(pics))
    except EOFError: pass

    temp = pics[0].convert('RGBA')
    gif['frames'] = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)]
    temp = pics[0]
    for item in pics[1:]:
        temp.paste(item)
        gif['frames'].append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp.convert('RGBA')))

    try: gif['delay'] = im.info['duration']
    except: pass
    gif['len'] = len(gif['frames'])
    return gif

def ratio(a,b):
    if b < a: d,c = a,b
    else: c,d = a,b
    if b == a: return 1,1
    for i in reversed(xrange(2,int(round(a / 2)))):
        if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0:
            a /= i
            b /= i
    return (int(a),int(b))

class App(Frame):
    def show(self,image=None,event=None):
        self.display.create_image((0,0),anchor=NW,image=image)   

    def animate(self,event=None):
        self.show(image=self.gif['frames'][self.gif['loc']])
        self.gif['loc'] += 1
        if self.gif['loc'] == self.gif['len']:
            self.gif['loc'] = 0
        if self.cont:
            threading.Timer((self.gif['delay'] / 1000),self.animate).start()

    def kill(self,event=None):
        self.cont = False
        sleep(0.1)
        self.quit()

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid(row=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.rowconfigure(1,weight=2)
        self.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.title = Label(self,text='No title')
        self.title.grid(row=0,sticky=E+W)
        self.display = Canvas(self)
        self.display.grid(row=1,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.user = Label(self,text='Posted by No Username')
        self.user.grid(row=2,sticky=E+W)
        self.comment = Text(self,height=4,width=40,state=DISABLED)
        self.comment.grid(row=3,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.cont = True
        self.gif = anim_gif('test.gif')
        self.animate()

        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.kill)


root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()

try: root.destroy()
except: pass
```

test.gif is the following GIF:

[image]

This works fine, but the GIF quality is terrible. I tried changing it to what follows:

```
def anim_gif(name):
    ## Returns { 'frames', 'delay', 'loc', 'len' }
    im = Image.open(name)
    gif = { 'frames': [],
            'delay': 100,
            'loc' : 0,
            'len' : 0 }
    pics = []
    try:
        while True:
            gif['frames'].append(im.copy())
            im.seek(len(gif['frames']))
    except EOFError: pass

    try: gif['delay'] = im.info['duration']
    except: pass
    gif['len'] = len(gif['frames'])
    return gif

class App(Frame):
    def show(self,image=None,event=None):
        can_w = self.display['width']
        can_h = self.display['height']

        pic_w,pic_h = image.size
        rat_w,rat_h = ratio(pic_w,pic_h)

        while pic_w > int(can_w) or pic_h > int(can_h):
            pic_w -= rat_w
            pic_h -= rat_h

        resized = image.resize((pic_w,pic_h))
        resized = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        self.display.create_image((0,0),anchor=NW,image=resized)
```

However, this will occasionally flash a picture. While the picture looks good, it's pretty useless as a program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing to do is figure out where the problem is. Try saving `temp` to a new .PNG file each time through the loop. Are they already screwed up? If so, Tkinter has nothing to do with the problem, which means you can write a much smaller [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Having looked at the code more carefully, and having done the suggested test for you: The problem is entirely in your PIL code; trying to fix the Tkinter stuff is chasing a wild goose up the wrong tree.

Comment: Related: [Play an Animated GIF with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43770847/190597)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one, you are creating a new canvas object for every frame. Eventually you will have thousands of images stacked on top of one another. This is highly inefficient; the canvas widget has performance issues when you start to have thousands of objects.

Instead of creating new image objects on the canvas, just reconfigure the existing object with the [itemconfig](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) method of the canvas.

Second, you don't need the complexities of threading for such a simple task. There is a well known pattern in tkinter for doing animations: draw a frame, then have that function use `after` to call itself in the future.

Something like this:

```
def animate(self):
    if self._image_id is None:
        self._image_id = self.display.create_image(...)
    else:
        self.itemconfig(self._image_id, image= the_new_image)
    self.display.after(self.gif["delay"], self.animate)
```

Finally, unless there's a strict reason to use a canvas, you can lower the complexity a little more by using a Label widget.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem has nothing to do with Tkinter. (For all I know, you may *also* have Tk problems, but your images are already bad before you get to Tk.)

The way I tested this was to modify your `anim_gif` function to write out the frames as separate image file, by changing the `for item in pics[1:]` loop like this:

```
 for i, item in enumerate(pics[1:]):
    temp.paste(item)
    temp.save('temp{}.png'.format(i))
    gif['frames'].append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp.convert('RGBA')))
```

The very first file, `temp0.png`, is already screwed up, with no Tk-related code being called.

In fact, you can test the same thing even more easily:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.gif')
temp = im.copy()
im.seek(1)
temp.paste(im.copy())
temp.save('test.png')
```

---

The problem is that you're pasting the pixels from frame #1 over top of the pixels from frame #0, but leaving the color palette from frame #0.

There are two easy ways to solve this.

First, use the RGBA-converted frames instead of the palette-color frames:

```
temp = pics[0].convert('RGBA')
gif['frames'] = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)]
for item in pics[1:]:
    frame = item.convert('RGBA')
    temp.paste(frame)
    gif['frames'].append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp))
```

Second, don't use copy and paste at all; just copy over each frame as an independent image:

```
gif['frames'] = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame.convert('RGBA')) for frame in pics]
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain why? This explains why the OP's code doesn't work, and how to fix it. Of course rewriting the whole thing in a smarter way while coincidentally not making the same mistake also solves the problem, but it doesn't explain what the OP was doing wrong.