# PIL distorting animated GIF quality when displaying in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I am having an issue with my code and am relatively new to using the `PIL library`. My code works, however the GIF is extremely bad quality and i'm not exactly sure how to fix it. My code is below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("****** Interface")
window.configure(background="white")

# Photo
class MyLabel(tkinter.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.resize((480, 270)).copy())
                im.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']

        except KeyError:
            self.delay = 45

        first = seq[0].convert('RGB')
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]

        tkinter.Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.frames[0])

        temp = seq[0].convert('RGB')
        for image in seq[1:]:
            frame = image.convert('RGB')
            temp.paste(frame)
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)        


lbl = MyLabel(window, '*****.gif')
lbl.pack(anchor="center")
window.mainloop()
```

I have taken a look at the solution provided at the link [Displaying animated GIFs in Tkinter using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223854/displaying-animated-gifs-in-tkinter-using-pil) however I could not get them to work. Please assist.

Comment: Have you tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770847/play-an-animated-gif-in-python-with-tkinter)? Worked pretty well for me.

Comment: That was actually the first answer I tried out, I still facing the same issue. Please help.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the quality of the gif not the actual code...the gif needs to be unoptimised.